# C socket read and write

Tags: c, sockets

I am confused with socket server/client read/write. I can write from client to server but I cannot figure out how to write back to client from server. Client gets in an infinite loop. Here is my code.

Server

```
sockdesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if ( sockdesc < 0 )
{
    cout << "Error creating socket" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
else{
    if ( getaddrinfo("0.0.0.0", portnum, NULL, &myinfo) != 0 )
    {
        cout << "Error getting address" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
if (bind(sockdesc, myinfo->ai_addr, myinfo->ai_addrlen) < 0 ){
    cout << "Error binding to socket" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
if ( listen(sockdesc, 1) < 0 ){
    cout << "Error in listen" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
connection = accept(sockdesc, NULL, NULL);
if ( connection < 0 ){
    cout << "Error in accept" << endl;
    exit(1);
}   
read(connection, (char*)&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
//some code goes here
//I do not know if i need to use connection or sockdesc in write(). When
//write back to client
write(connection, (char*)&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
```

Client

```
sockdesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if ( sockdesc < 0 ){
    cout << "Error opening socket" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
if ( getaddrinfo(hostname, portnum, NULL, &myinfo) != 0 ){
    cout << "Error getting address" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
connection = connect(sockdesc, myinfo->ai_addr, myinfo->ai_addrlen);
if ( connection < 0 ){
    cout << "Error in connect" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
write(sockdesc, (char*)&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
//some code goes here
//I do not know if i need to use connection or sockdesc in read()
read(sockdesc, (char*)&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
```

Comment: You should definitely examine the values returned by read() and write(), and errno if they are negative.If you still have questions afterwards, please come back with a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I check return values and make error check, no doubt on that. I just posted basic code to reduce verbage which will be easy for everybody. basic code as it shown write to server and get the data back from server. But how to implement read and write in both server and client.Hope this gives you better insight about my question.

Comment: You need to `write()` using the same socket that you `read()` from, and vice versa.  On the server side, `read()` and `write()` using the socket returned by `accept()`. On the client side, `write()` and `read()` using the socket returned by `socket()`. The code you have shown is fine, so whatever problems you are having are in code you have not shown yet. For instance, you say the client is stuck in an infinite loop, but there is no loop in the code you have shown. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).