# C TCP write() and read() from sockets defined in main

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

## Information

**Problem:**  I am trying to set-up TCP socket `read()` and `write()` from the same main function, however I am unsure how to correctly read from the socket.

**Background info:** I have communication working with separate executables, one for the Reading(Server) and the other for Writing(Client).

To do this I used this site for guidance. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/

I understand from Remy Lebeau's comment on [C socket read and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347477/c-socket-read-and-write) that the socket returned by `accept()` is used by the Server and the socket returned from `socket()` is used by the Client.

I have the writing to the socket working correctly.

```
Awaiting message from a client...
Address: 2, Port: 4547
Socket: 4
Serv addr: -1894572528
Size of server: 16
Message to send to server: hey
sendBytes: 3: hey
Recv bytes: 0
Recieved message:
```

## Code

The program is comprised of three functions

**main()**

**createTcpRcvSock()**

**createTcpSendSock()**

## Functions headers and their bodies

**main(), includes and definitions**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 4547
int main(){

    int recvSock,sendSock,recvN,sendN,bufferSize,acceptSock,clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;

    char sendBuffer[256];
    char recvBuffer[256];

    recvSock = createTcpRecvSock();

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    acceptSock = accept(recvSock, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, clilen);

    sendSock = createTcpSendSock();

    printf("Message to send to server: ");

    bzero(sendBuffer,256);
    scanf("%s",&sendBuffer);
    bufferSize = strlen(sendBuffer);
    sendN = write(sendSock,sendBuffer,bufferSize);
    printf("sendBytes: %d: %s\n",sendN,sendBuffer);
    if(sendN < 0){
        printf("Error writing to socket\n");
    }

    bzero(recvBuffer,256);
    bufferSize = strlen(recvBuffer);
    recvN = read(acceptSock,recvBuffer,bufferSize);
    printf("Recv bytes: %d\n", recvN);
    if(recvN < 0){
        printf("Error reading from socket\n");
    }
    printf("Recieved message: %s\n",recvBuffer);
}
```

**createTcpSendSock()**

```
int createTcpSendSock(){
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0){
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    printf("Socket: %d\n", sockfd);
    printf("Serv addr: %d\n", &serv_addr);
    printf("Size of server: %d\n", sizeof(serv_addr));
    
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr ,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){ 
        printf("Error connecting: %d:  %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    }
    return sockfd;
}
```

**createTcpRecvSock()**

```
int createTcpRecvSock(){

    int sockfd,portno,clilen,opt;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    opt = 1;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    }
    printf("Success opeing socket\n");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))){
        printf("Setting socket options error: %d: %s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    printf("Awaiting message from a client...\n");
    printf("Address: %d, Port: %d\n", AF_INET, PORT);

    if(
    bind(sockfd,
    (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, 
    sizeof(serv_addr))
     < 0)
    {
        printf("Error on binding: %d, %s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    listen(sockfd,6);

    return sockfd;
}
```

**Expected**

I would expect the output `Received message: <User entered message>`

**Actual**

But the program hangs on this even though there isn't a loop:

```
Success opeing socket
Awaiting message from a client...
Address: 2, Port: 4547
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated, I've tried to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: You are trying to accept as a server before you have connected as a  client. This doesn't make the least sense.  You need to read some better documentaton. Your citation is complete drivel from start to finish. You can't just rely on arbitrary Internet garbage and then go round asking why it doesn't work. There are so many things wrong with this code, and the concepts behind it, that frankly it defies belief.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks, I missed accepting before connecting as a client. Is there any documentation you could recommend, also maybe an elaboration on even one of the many things wrong with my code? I'm here to learn after all.

Comment: There is a thing out there called Beej's guide to networking which isn't bad, but your primary source must be the *man* pages, such as they are. You need to error-check every system call. You need to use the length returned by `read()` when using the data, for example if `read()` into `data` returns `n` and `n > 0`, use `printf("%.*s", n, data);`. A socket that is listening is a listening socket, not a receiving socket. And so on.

Comment: And `listen()` and `accept()` are for server sockets; `connect()` is for client sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation for Beej's guide. Looks very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user **user207421** pointed out, I was accepting a client before connecting.

Also `acceptSock = accept(recvSock, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, clilen);`

Should be `acceptSock = accept(recvSock, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);`

`socklen_t *addrlen` parameter of `accept()` requires pointer, I was not passing a pointer.

Adding the **&** before the size parameter changes this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string functions when you know the length some other way. It will get you into trouble.

```
bzero(recvBuffer,256);
bufferSize = strlen(recvBuffer);
recvN = read(acceptSock,recvBuffer,bufferSize);
```

You empty the buffer so it contains just zeroes. Since zero bytes mark the end of the string, `strlen` will return zero. So you're trying to read with a buffer that you are claiming is zero bytes in size.

The `strlen` function does NOT EVER tell you how much space is available. It tells you how big the string data is. If there's no string data there, then it makes no sense to call `strlen`.

Then you do this:

```
printf("Recieved message: %s\n",recvBuffer);
```

While it will probably work with the way your code currently is, this is a bad habit to get into. The `read` function returned `recvN`, the number of bytes you received. You ignore this and ask `printf` to figure out what to print from just the data. Don't do this. It will eventually cause you trouble. Use `recvN` to know how many bytes to print.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I use recvN just to check if any data is returned for debugging. How would I use recvN to know how many bytes to print? Is this using a for loop?

Comment: The `printf` function has format specifiers that let you specify the number of characters to print. But if you don't know how to do that, then you can use a `for` loop. Do not use string functions like `strcpy` and `strlen` unless you are 100% confident that you have a string stored somewhere. Arbitrary data is not a string.